# how doing do, can registry-registry-role be eliminated?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Using playbook where I'm Ansible, openshift-origin, I built by the following 3 nodes:

- master
- node01
- node02

After building had been completed, status in docker-registry was Pending, so docker-registry was eliminated by the following commands:

```
oc delete dc/docker-registry
oc delete svc/docker-registry
oc delete pod docker-registry-5-deploy
```

After completion, elimination of docker-registry made docker registry in following command newly.

```
oadm registry
```

Result:

```
Creating registry registry ...
error: serviceaccounts "registry" already exists
error: rolebinding "registry-registry-role" already exists
deploymentconfig "docker-registry" created
service "docker-registry" created
Failed
```

Elimination method of serviceaccounts was understood in this error.
But a way of elimination of rolebinding "registry-registry-role" isn't understood.

How should this be operated?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the clusterrolebinding registry-registry-role with this Openshift command:

```
oc delete clusterrolebindings registry-registry-role
```

For more info [View roles of users in Openshift cluster](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/admin_solutions/user_role_mgmt.html#view-roles-users-cluster)